# Windows Phone: How to Navigate another page which is using DispatcherTimer?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have two pages Main.xaml which includes only a button and another page timer.xaml which includes a timer. After pressing the button in the main page I want to go to the another page and start timer. I am using following code:

```
enter code here

**Main Page:** 
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/timer.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}


**timer Page:**

     public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
        counter=0;
        count.Text = counter.ToString();

    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       counter++;
       count.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
```

I can not see time in the timer page however, after pressing the button it will navigate to the timer page correctly but I can not see updates in my timer page. I am debugging my code and it seems that DistpacherTimer() works correctly but my timer page does not update.    Do you know how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could find the problem. the code that you can see above was not whole code that I have written. Actually, in my real code I was sending a list <>  from main page to timer page. Passing data from one page to another page is a little tricky. My main problem was that I did not send the data from main page to timer page in correct way, so that caused problem. Thus, there was nothing wrong with my DispatcherTimer() class or Event handler.

In other words, the code above works well if you do not pass data (e.g. list, array and so on) from a page to another page in a wrong way.